# Pivot multiple columns and rows in Spark Sql

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I have below data.

[image]

I have to pivot in Spark Sql to get below result

[image]

Have tried many ways, its little complicated to perform in AWS Glue.
Any suggestion would be helpful.

Below is what is have tried,

````
(select * from category_data
unpivot
(
categoreval
for a in (e1, e2)
));```
````

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: [How to Transpose Spark/PySpark DataFrame](https://nikhil-suthar-bigdata.medium.com/how-to-transpose-spark-dataframe-fa82c079a6b)

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object ColumnToRowDataframe extends App {

  val spark = SparkSession.builder
    .master("local[*]")
    .appName("Task_1")
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  val df1 = Seq(
    ("Michel", "01-08-1999", "NY"),
    ("Joel", "02-08-1999", "WT")
  ).toDF("Name", "Dob", "Place")

  df1.show(false)
  //  +------+----------+-----+
  //  |Name  |Dob       |Place|
  //  +------+----------+-----+
  //  |Michel|01-08-1999|NY   |
  //  |Joel  |02-08-1999|WT   |
  //  +------+----------+-----+

  val resDF = TransposeDF(df1, Seq("Dob", "Place"), "Name")
    .withColumnRenamed("Name", "Val")

  resDF.show(false)
  //  +-----+----------+----------+
  //  |Val  |Joel      |Michel    |
  //  +-----+----------+----------+
  //  |Place|WT        |NY        |
  //  |Dob  |02-08-1999|01-08-1999|
  //  +-----+----------+----------+

  // https://nikhil-suthar-bigdata.medium.com/how-to-transpose-spark-dataframe-fa82c079a6b
  def TransposeDF(df: DataFrame, columns: Seq[String], pivotCol: String): DataFrame = {
    val columnsValue = columns.map(x => "'" + x + "', " + x)
    val stackCols = columnsValue.mkString(",")
    val df_1 = df.selectExpr(pivotCol, "stack(" + columns.size + "," + stackCols + ")")
      .select(pivotCol, "col0", "col1")

    val final_df = df_1.groupBy(col("col0")).pivot(pivotCol).agg(concat_ws("", collect_list(col("col1"))))
      .withColumnRenamed("col0", pivotCol)
    final_df
  }
}
```